# no implicit conversion of String into Integer Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm doing a dropdown field that gets it's values from another controller, I defined it like this:

```
def dropdown
        @tarefa_list = Tarefa.all.map { |c| [c.Numero] [c.Resumo]}
     end
```

and call it like this:

```
<%= f.select :Tarefa, @tarefa_list, {}, {class: "dropdown"} %>
```

Numero being a integer and Resumo being a string

the error im getting when I try to view the form:

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

- What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `Tarefa.all.map { |c| [c.Numero, c.Resumo] }` OR `Tarefa.all.map { |c| [ c.Resumo, c.Numero] }` assuming `Numero` is identifier..

Comment: now it's only showing the first identifier, if I put `c.numero` first it only shows `numero` and if I put `c.Resumo` first it only shows `resumo`

Comment: @xdmanmagiconsei  `@tarefa_list` has proper value ?

Comment: I am just defining it there, do I need to define something some where else?

Comment: I have a tarefas_controller defining tarefa with Resumo Numero numemp and Tarefa, and I want just those 2 to be on the f.select field

Comment: Try this one `<%= f.select :tarefas, Tarefa.all.map { |c| [c.Numero] [c.Resumo]}, :prompt => 'Select One',{class: "dropdown"} %>`

Comment: `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: Please post result of `Tarefa.all.map { |c| [c.Numero] [c.Resumo]}`

Comment: @xdmanmagiconsei in reagrds to *"now it's only showing the first identifier, if I put c.numero first it only shows numero and if I put c.Resumo first it only shows resumo"*. You are correct because the first element is the display and the other is the value look at the HTML generated. `<option value="some_numero">Some Resumo</option>` I guess you could do `Tarefa.all.map { |c| [ "#{c.Resumo} #{c.Numero}", c.Numero] }` if you wanted the value will still be `c.Numero` but the display value will show both.

Comment: a simple `+` in between them resolved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
@tarefa_list = Tarefa.all.map { |c| [c.Numero, c.Resumo] }
```

And then:

```
<%= f.select :Tarefa do %>
  <% @tarefa_list.each do |c| -%>
    <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's not pretty but we can start from here.

(based on: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models)

Btw I think the `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` comes from the fact that expression `[c.Numero] [c.Resumo]` tries to get the `c.Resumo` element of an array defined of `[c.Numero]` So something like `[1,2,3]['a']`
As you can imagine it won't work.